# Change Popup window title using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.showModalDialog` in current apps. How can change title based on upon some conditions in javascript? Can anybody help on this. Please don't consider duplicate post. I tried different ways to change title:

1. `window.document.title="Add Cartons"`
2. `var results=window.showModelDialog(url,"Add Cartons",windowarguments)`

But I can't successes.

Please help on this.

Comment: What's the browser that you are using? If you are using IE, there's a BUG with it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263033

Comment: Yes I am using IE7 & 8 Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
       window.document.title = "yourtitle";
        if (window.dialogArguments) {
            window.opener = window.dialogArguments;
        }
        function setTitle() {
            document.title = "NewTitle";
            alert(document.title)

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a new title via `dialog arguments` argument, just like you've tried:

```
var results = window.showModalDialog(url, 'Add Cartons', windowarguments);
```

And then in a script *in the dialog*:

```
document.title = window.dialogArguments;
```

Though looks like they haven't fixed the `showModalDialog()` in Chrome yet. So this is not going to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a detailed solution over this problem. Please refer to

[support.microsoft.com/kb/263033](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263033)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change *the title of the window you're calling (the popup)*, **not** *the one from which you're calling the popup*. So, put `<title>Add Cartons</title>` inside the head of your popup and it will show up.

To modify it based on the popup call, use the arguments, read them from the popup and dynamically change the title.